# what is _(number) in prolog, and why when they appear winHugs freezes?

Tags: variables, prolog

The following code works OK

```
longitud([],0).
longitud([_|Xs],Cont):-
    longitud(Xs,ContAux),
    Cont is ContAux + 1.
```

but when I make a consult, like...

```
longitud (X, 1).
```

it says something like

```
X=[_512]
```

and winhugs just freezes.
what is that _(number) thing and why does it freeze?

Comment: `_512` is the internal representation of a variable name. What Prolog tells you with that answer is that a list of 1 element (that element being a variable with any value) is valid for `X` when you pass 1 as the second argument. It "freezes" because it thinks there might be other possible answers. Pressing `;` will make Prolog look for other values and it will tell you `false`, i.e. there are no other solutions.

Comment: @Fatalize, if I consult `1 ?- longitud(X,Y).` it answers 
`X = [],
Y = 0 ;
X = [_G210],
Y = 1 ;
X = [_G210, _G213],
Y = 2 ;
X = [_G210, _G213, _G216],`
till I press . + intro (... so can we say it is inversible?)

but if I consult `2 ?- longitud(X,1).`
it answers
`X = [_G323] `, and then when I press `;` it just freezes, instead if I just press `.` after the first answer, it let's me make another consult... so `;` freezes and doesn't seem to try to find another answer.

Comment: That's because your code is incorrect. You need to add `Cont > 0` at the beginning of your second rule, otherwise when you press `;` it will loop infinitely.

Comment: @Fatalize, actually, now it says `ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated` even for consults that were working before, it looks like the code NOW is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking your code down step by step, here's what's happening. You can see this if you run a `trace` and execute your code as well:

When you query:

```
longitud(X, 1).
```

Prolog will find the first matching predicate clause. `logitud([], 0).` does not match since `1` and `0` cannot be unified. However, `longitude([_|Xs], Cont)` will match since Prolog can successfully unify `X` with `[_|Xs]` and `Cont` with `1`.

The first argument in your second predicate clause has the anonymous variable `_` and you've just unified `[_|Xs]` with `X`. So at this point, we know `X` is a list with a head element that is anonymous, and a tail `Xs`.

When the rest of your predicate executes, Prolog calls `longitud(Xs, ContAux)`, which will match the first clause, `longitud([], 0)`, unifying `Xs` with `[]` and `ContAux` with `0`. At this point, `X` is unified with `[_|[]]` or simply `[_]`. When Prolog displays anonymous variables in results, it needs a way to distinguish all of them since every occurrence of an anonymous variable is different. Even though they all have the name `_`, they are not all representing the same variable in your program. Prolog will append a designation, such as `_G123` to indicate the anonymous variable.And that is why your results are `X = [_512]`.

Your implementation of `longitud/2` looks like it defines a relation in which the second argument represents the length of the list given by the first argument. The query `longitud(X, 1)` is a query that produces a list `X` that has length of 1. The result `X = [_512]` is completely legitimate since Prolog is saying that `X` is a list of one element, we just don't know what that element is. If you had queried, `longitud(X, 2)` you would have seen something like, `X = [_512, _513]`.

The code freezes for reasons @Fatalize indicated: you don't have a condition to constrain the count to be >= 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens in SWI-Prolog, after the modification suggested.

```
?- [user].
|: longitud([],0).
|: longitud([_|Xs],Cont):-
|:     Cont>0,
|:     longitud(Xs,ContAux),
|:     Cont is ContAux + 1.
(Ctrl+D here...)
|: true.

?- leash(-all),trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- longitud(X,1).
   Call: (8) longitud(_7016, 1)
   Call: (9) 1>0
   Exit: (9) 1>0
   Call: (9) longitud(_7208, _7228)
   Exit: (9) longitud([], 0)
   Call: (9) 1 is 0+1
   Exit: (9) 1 is 0+1
   Exit: (8) longitud([_7206], 1)
X = [_7206] ;
   Redo: (9) longitud(_7208, _7228)
   Call: (10) _7232>0
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] _7686>0
ERROR:    [9] longitud([_7718|_7720],_7714) at user://2:30
ERROR:    [8] longitud([_7750,_7756|_7758],1) at user://2:30
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

As @lurker explained, it's the redo of the call labeled `(9)` that causes the infinite recursion. The condition `Cont>0` just causes an instantiation error.

Since longitud/2 appears to be just a naive implementation of the ISO builtin [length](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2)/2, let's take a (partial) look to it:

```
    % Execution Aborted
    [trace]  ?- edit(length).
    true.

length(List, Length) :-
    var(Length), !,
    '$skip_list'(Length0, List, Tail),
    ... etc etc
length(List, Length) :-
    integer(Length),
    Length >= 0, !,
    '$skip_list'(Length0, List, Tail),
    ... etc etc
```

$skip_list/3 it's an internal implementation detail, what's worth to note it's that you must handle the case when Length is a variable (as in the case of the call labelled `(9)`).